# Create screenshot of the same part of the screen repeatedly

Tags: browser

I know there are 23432 (est.) plugins to create screenshots of (part of) your screen (in a browser). But for dev/doc purposes, I want to /repeatedly/ make a shot of the /same/ part of the screen. I do not want to need to draw the same rectangle tens of times. (Apart from the fact that it will never be exactly the same...) Anybody got a good plugin for that? I am on OS X, but I can access a Windows box if need be. I don't care if it is Firefox/Chrome/IE...

regards,

Paul

Comment: Funny; I got a badge with this question because nobody answered it. But I still feel it is a valid question... any takers?...

Comment: I don't suppose you mean like a screen recording program like this describes: http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/01/how-to-record-your-screen-in-mac-os-x.html?m=1

Comment: Not really; I would want something (plugin?) to create screenshots of a small part of the screen on keypress or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an AppleScript to take a screenshot and then using an image editing tool to clip the image to just the portion you want?  Something similar has been documented here:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1214952?start=0&tstart=0

The Mac's 'screencapture' terminal tool is pretty neat, but does not seem to include an option to specify the coordinates for the screenshot.

Comment: Thats a good idea - but it is not what I wanted :-( I wanted to be able to do this from within the browser, as I need to be able to control the taking of the screenshot from JS. But I welcome the idea! :-)